# $\sigma$-algebra generated by a sum of functions

Tags: measure-theory

Is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by a finite sum of functions the same one as that generated by the set of those functions ? I'm trying to work it out but all I can get is stuff like $(X+Y)^{-1}(]-\infty,a[)=\displaystyle \cup_{t\in \mathbb{R}} (X^{-1}(\lbrace{t}\rbrace) \cap Y^{-1}(]-\infty, a-t[))$ which is already a bit of a mess since my reunion is uncountable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Tomasz's hint, I'm going to answer my own question for the benefit of other readers :
Suppose the functions $X$ and $Y$ have $\Omega$ as their domain ($\Omega$ isn't yet a measurable space). Let $A\subset\Omega$ (nonempty), $X=1_A$ and therefore $Y=-1_A$. Then $X+Y=0$ hence $\sigma(X+Y)=\lbrace{\emptyset, \Omega \rbrace}$. But $X$ alone generates the $\sigma$-algebra $\lbrace{\emptyset, A, A^c, \Omega \rbrace}$ (in fact $Y$ generates the same one).
However, I have just proved, if not mistaken, that $\sigma(X+Y) \subset \sigma(X,Y)$ using the fact that $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}$ $(X+Y)^{-1}(]-\infty,a[)=\displaystyle \cup_{q\in \mathbb{Q}} (X^{-1}(]-\infty, q[) \cap Y^{-1}(]-\infty, a-q[))$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Let $X$ be your favourite nonconstant function, and $Y=-X$.